# set elements position (x , y ) to form a circle or any other shape in react native

Tags: flexbox, position, react-native

I have a bunch of Button component which I want them to form a circle , triangle or .. So i think I should set the positions x and y for each element after some calculation , is there any way I can set positions for element in react native or is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: As SO is not a code writing service, you need to provide a initial working code snippet.

Comment: @LGson I didn't get your point buddy , could you explain more

Comment: The question should contain a minimal working code snippet within itself, reproducing the issue. Read more here how to ask questions properly: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve